# Installing NetSerivce NDIS Filter Driver on Windows IoT Core

Tags: windows, ndis, windows-10-iot-core, filter-driver

I know that there is a simple driver example to install a device driver on IoT Core. I cannot find any information about how to install a NetService type NDIS filter driver on IoT Core. I have trouble installing a NDIS Filter Driver on IoT Core, which is quite different from a general device driver.

My NDIS filter driver is basically from VS2015 NDIS filter driver sample. I already successfully put it on a target Win 10 Enterprise PC and can see its trace messages via VS2015 Kernel debugger window from Development computer.

I was also trying to put it on Windows IoT Core, and my hardware is Minnowboard Max. My steps are:

1. Follow
   https://ms-iot.github.io/content/en-US/win10/samples/DriverLab4.htm 
   to just set up the provisioning on the target IoT Core from VS2015
   on dev computer.
2. Follow
   https://channel9.msdn.com/Blogs/WinHEC/Creating-Universal-Drivers-with-WDK-10
   to prepare for the mobile package (.cab file). Need to enter the
   required info in Package.pkg.xml file. Build the x86 debug version.
3. Follow the same link as bullet 2 to deploy the .cab (online .cab package installation/update) on IoT
   Core from VS2015.

   However, after connected via Kernel Debugger and set Kd_DEFAULT_MASK
   = 0xF,  cannot see any filter driver’s trace messages.

   “devcon listclass NetService” returns empty.

Can anyone give me any instructions or hint? (This issue
 is only for IoT Core. I successfully made it work on Windows 10 Enterprise already.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately I don't think that NDIS LWFs can be installed onto Windows IoT Core currently.  What's the high-level problem you're trying to solve?  Maybe there's another way to solve this problem that doesn't involve LWFs.